# SPARQL, Comma separated parameter into multiple query objects

Tags: rdf, sparql, virtuoso

I have the IRI

`http://localhost:8080/drinks/coke,pepsi,fanta`

which is automatically generated and I want to reformat it in the following objects so I will get a query that looks something like below

```
SELECT * WHERE 
    {
      ?person ?p <http://localhost:8080/drinks/coke> .
      ?person ?p <http://localhost:8080/drinks/pepsi> .
      ?person ?p <http://localhost:8080/drinks/fanta> .
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AndyS's answer is right that there's no convenient way to do this, but there are some options if you *really* have to work with an IRI like the one you have.  Using regular expressions you can explode the string of the IRI that you have into one that contains the IRI strings of the three IRIs that you want:

```
select ?url ?urls where {
  values ?url { <http://localhost:8080/drinks/coke,pepsi,fanta> }
  bind(replace(str(?url), "(^.*/).*$","$1") as ?prefix)
  bind(concat(",",strafter(str(?url),?prefix)) as ?parts)
  bind(replace(?parts,",",concat(" ",?prefix)) as ?urls)
}
```

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| url                                             | urls                                                                                                       |
================================================================================================================================================================
| <http://localhost:8080/drinks/coke,pepsi,fanta> | " http://localhost:8080/drinks/coke http://localhost:8080/drinks/pepsi http://localhost:8080/drinks/fanta" |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Using this, you could do a query wherein you can filter an IRI based on whether its strign is present in the larger string.  That obviously has some potential for fase positives, since any substring would also register.  You can filter with something likk this:

```
?s ?p ?o .
filter contains(?urls,str(?s))
```

Answer (score 2):

SPARQL does not have loops on expressions nor sequences values for variables.
You could format when creating the query string or use string operations.

```
SELECT * WHERE 
    {
      ?person ?p ?o .
      FILTER STRSTARTS(str(?o), "http://localhost:8080/drinks/") 
    }
```

See also `REPLACE` etc if you want to compute "http://localhost:8080/drinks/" in a query.

Comment: So basically that means that amount of comma separated parameters should be fixed?